# Cannot get a kubeconfig for a ServiceAccount to work correctly

Tags: kubernetes

I have an issue with creating namespaces, serviceaccounts, roles, rolebindings and kubeconfig files.

In the future we will have multiple teams/ applications landing on Kubernetes and I want to create a namespace per team.
We are using Kubernetes on Azure (AKS) and the default created kubeconfig is not something to just handover to all teams. So I thought I would create a serviceaccount per namespace and create a role + rolebinding. 
So I tried it locally with minikube.

I first created the resources:

[image]

And then I created the config file for the serviceaccount:
[image]

But with this config file I can still see all resources in all namespaces and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Hopefully someone can help me out.

Kind regards,
Bram

Comment: Could you update the question and replace screenshot with code as a code pls, to make your question readable.

Comment: Hi Nick, I tried that but somehow it keeps messing up the formatting. that is why I used screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration looks well, but service-accounts are designed for accessing Kubernetes from the inside of cluster or for accessing it by other services.

In your case, the better option would be using `User` with a role binding.

Here is a [good instruction](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/#use-case-1-create-user-with-limited-namespace-access) from Bitnami how to do that.

In a few words, you should:

1. Create The User Credentials
2. Create The Role For Managing Deployments
3. Bind The Role To The Employee User

Regarding your problem, please check your Minikube configuration and ensure that RBAC is enabled.

You can use `--extra-config=apiserver.Authorization.Mode=RBAC` option to launch minikube with enforced RBAC authorization.